# Android: Facebook login dialog does not show soft keyboard

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK v3.17.1 and use LoginButton for basic authentication.

I tested it in my Nexus 5 and it is working properly, after pressing the login button the prompt appears that requires confirmation for the permission.

However, when I run it on my Nexus 7, I was required to login first even though I already have a native FB app (in Nexus 5, there is no login), so I tried to enter my login details. But I can't enter any text because the soft keyboard is not showing even if I tap on the input field.

Is this a device problem or there is something wrong with Facebook SDK? I tried it on Galaxy Note and the issue also occurs. In Galaxy S3, the issue is not occuring. I'm a bit confused on what is happening.

Thanks for any help.

Link for the Nexus 7 screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIKJl.png

Comment: I am using the Facebook SDK 3.16 and having the exact same problem with a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3. Were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to flushing your router/wifi and renew your IP. I just read an article about it and it says there is a problem with Facebook apps in case of Android tablets.
So may be you could trying doing that to see if you tablet supports Facebook app log in. It did work for me.